# GC Out of Memory in Drools Rule Engine in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, out-of-memory, drools, rule-engine

I need to compare data of two `List`s based on two fields and if the data matches then add it to another list.

The Rule I have written is working fine but when I'm trying to test it for more records(say 10,000 records) it's throwing GC `Out of Memory error`.

For this I'm adding Both the lists(facts) in the working memory.The code for adding it is given below:

```
   // insert List 1
    list1.stream().forEach(p -> kieSession.insert(p));
    // insert List 2
    list2.stream().forEach(p ->kieSession.insert(p));
```

Both these lists have the same fields.Now, I need to check if the data of field1 and field2 of list1 matches with that of list2.The code of the Rule I've written is as follows:

```
       rule "To check list1 and list2" 
        salience 5
        no-loop true
           when
                list1: List1($field1:field1,$field2:field2)
                list2: List2($field1List2:field1,$field2List2:field2)
                eval($field1List2==$field1&&$field2List2==$field2)
            then
                globalList.add(list2);
                retract(list1);
                retract(list2);
        end
```

I'm not able to figure out the cause of `GC out of memory`.

Whether I'm doing something wrong with the Rules or I need to increase JVM memory?

Currently, the JVM memory is `-Xms2048m`.

Answer (score 1):

Drools is based on Rete arithmetic, so it will take O(m*n) time and memory to do the CROSS-JOIN work, which causes bad performance and OOM easily. Try not to write join condition in rules, do the join work outside the work memory.

Comment: So, how should I handle a condition like this? Should I check such a condition with a Java code? Or is there any way I can do it with drools?

Comment: I think there is no good way to do it in drools rules, you should just build the global List before inserting Lists into drools session.